# Using Java to verify signature created in Golang

Tags: java, go, digital-signature, x509

I'm creating a signature in Go, for example:

```
//I'm reading a file with -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
privateKeyPem := strings.Replace(privateKeyString, `\n`, "\n", -1) //file has '/n' instead of break lines for dev purposes
block, _ := pem.Decode([]byte(privateKeyPem))
key, _ := x509.ParsePKCS1PrivateKey(block.Bytes)
hashedString := sha256.Sum256([]byte(stringTosign))
signature, err = rsa.SignPKCS1v15(rand.Reader, key, crypto2.SHA256, hashedString[:])
signatureString := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(signature)
```

Java program receives the variable signatureString and does:

```
byte[] keyBytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("./golangSignerPubKey.der"));
X509EncodedKeySpec spec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
PublicKey publicKey =  kf.generatePublic(spec);
Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA", "BC");
signature.initVerify(publicKey);
signature.update(stringUnsigned.getBytes());
boolean signatureIsValid = signature.verify(Base64.getDecoder().decode(signatureString.getBytes()));
```

But the signatureIsValid boolean is always false, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Have You verified that You can decode it in Go ? This will make finding the error easier.

Comment: Yes, i'm verifying the signature after creating it to see if it is working (the verification is successful):
clientCertEndorserSignToVerify, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(signatureSTring)
errVerify := rsa.VerifyPKCS1v15(publicKey.(*rsa.PublicKey), crypto2.SHA256, hashedString, signatureString)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to verify the signature. I'm posting here in case someone comes across this with the same question:

Signature creation in Go:

```
bytesToSign := []byte (stringToSign)
block, err8 := pem.Decode([]byte(privateKeyPem)) //-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----
if err8 != nil {
    logger.Debugf("Error trying decode endorser private key")
}
key, _ := x509.ParsePKCS1PrivateKey(block.Bytes)
h := sha256.New()
h.Write(bytesToSign)
d := h.Sum(nil)
signature, err = rsa.SignPKCS1v15(rand.Reader, key, crypto.SHA256, d)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
signatureString = base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(signature)
```

Signature verification in Java (receives signatureString):
I have the public key in a .pub file and:

```
byte[] keyBytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("./public_key.pub"));
String temp = new String(keyBytes);
String publicKeyPEM = temp.replace("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n", "");
publicKeyPEM = publicKeyPEM.replace("\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----", "");
BASE64Decoder b64= new BASE64Decoder();
byte[] decoded = b64.decodeBuffer(publicKeyPEM);
X509EncodedKeySpec spec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(decoded);
KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
publicKey = kf.generatePublic(spec);
Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA", "BC");
signature.initVerify(publicKey);
signature.update(bytesToVerify); //bytesToVerify = bytesToSign in go
byte[] signatureDecoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(signatureString);
boolean endorserSignatureIsValid = signature.verify(signatureDecoded);
//It is now valid
```

I was not able to use Base64.getDecoder() (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character a) to decode the publicKeyPEM so I used BASE64Decoder. Not sure why.

Comment: PEM files (like MIME but not XML or JSON) have the base64 broken into lines. Java8+ `Base64.getDecoder()` is for 'basic' base64 with _no_ linebreaks; for linebreaks like MIME use `Base64.getMimeDecoder()` as explained [in the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html). Alternatively delete all `\n` or `\r\n` depending on your system or file(s) before decoding.

Answer (score 1):

I had also encounted this issue yesterday, and I solved it finally.

It's may help others: https://github.com/xioxu/signature_in_multiple_lang